# Rails check_box: checked if for a new record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4

In a Rails 4 `form_for` form, I'm have:

`f.check_box :visible`

I want the checkbox to be rendered as *checked* when rendering the form for a *brand new* (ie unsaved) object.

When the object is saved, I want the checkbox to behave normally (ie be checked or not checked based on the value of the saved object).

This works:

`f.object.new_record? ? (f.check_box :visible, :checked => true) : (f.check_box :visible)`

.. but it's pretty long! Is there a simpler/better way I can accomplish this?

Comment: Why not set visible to true on the unsaved record?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
f.check_box :visible, checked: ( f.object.new_record? || f.object.visible )
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set the attribute to true when you create your new object in the controller:

```
def new
   @model = Model.new(visible: true)
end
```